# Minimizimg an activity in previous activities in android

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle, back-stack

I'm developing a video call component that supports instant messaging. I want to add the option of minimizing the video call screen on back pressed and return to the messaging `activity` to do both at the same time (a WhatsApp like a feature). The problem is, I can't find a solution to this since going back to a previous `activity` will finish the current one. So how can I `override` my `onBackpressed()` so that I can minimize instead of finishing the call screen `activity` (let's say add it to the notification) and return to the messaging `activity`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is called [Picture-in-Picture](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/picture-in-picture).

> Android 8.0 (API level 26) allows activities to launch in
>   picture-in-picture (PIP) mode. PIP is a special type of multi-window
>   mode mostly used for video playback. It lets the user watch a video in
>   a small window pinned to a corner of the screen while navigating
>   between apps or browsing content on the main screen.

A very minimalistic example:

**1)** Specify in your `AndroidManifest` file which activity supports PIP:

```
<activity
      android:name=".VideoActivity"
      android:configChanges="screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|orientation"
      android:resizeableActivity="true"
      android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"/>
```

**2)** Trigger the PIP mode in response to some user action, for example in `onBackPressed()`:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
   // Ideally you would want to enter PIP while a video is playing, so:
   val isVideoPlaying = // have a condition here that holds true while the video is playing

   if (isVideoPlaying) {
        enterPictureInPictureMode()
   } else {
        super.onBackPressed()
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I understand what you're saying, but this not exactly what I want. I don't really care about picture in picture and play back video. I just want to be able to maintain the call in my app even if it is a voice call so the user can also message and do other stuff while the call is ongoing. So I just want to hide the call somewhere in my previous activities when the back button is clicked and I want to support it on older versions of android.

Comment: Well, that is slightly different from what you asked: "I want to add the option of *minimizing the video call screen*" - which you would have done with PIP... Now, for maintaing the call in the app so the user can also message and do other stuff while the call is ongoing, would imply decoupling your call logic from the `Activity`. That is, if you don't want your call to be ended when the `Activity` is destroyed, move it out of the `Activity`. An alternative would be to put the call logic in a `Service`. A `Service` runs in background and is not bound to the `Activity` lifecycle.

Comment: Did you get any solution for minimize activity like whats app call? I want to minimize app while call is running like whats app

Comment: same problem here.. anyone found any solution yet?